# Transform the Gordon-Klein equation to a system of first order PDEs but not using Dirac's approach

Tags: linear-pde

This is the Gordon-Klein equation:  $\frac{\partial^2 \psi }{\partial t^2} - c^2 (\frac{\partial^2 \psi }{\partial x^2} +\frac{\partial^2 \psi }{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \psi }{\partial z^2} ) +m^2c^4 \psi =0$ , where the reduced Planck constant is left out for convenience. The Dirac equation is the result of factorising the Gordon-Klein equation into a system of first order PDEs. But I feel that something has been left out of the original Gordon-Klein equation by this factorisation. I wonder if there is an alternative way of expressing the Gordon-Klein equation into another system of first order PDEs which corresponds exactly to the original Gordon-Klein equation.

Comment: By something missing, do you mean the cross terms we'd naively get by squaring (in the sense of operators) the Dirac equation? [Anticommutation relations on matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation#Dirac's_coup) prevent such cross terms, which the Klein-Gordon equation isn't meant to have anyway.

Comment: I am aware of this. The Gamma matrices take care of the unwanted terms. But I feel that factorisation may leave something out from the original equation. I have seen other ways of transforming a linear second order PDE into a system of linear first order PDEs, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391707/splitting-a-2nd-order-pde-into-a-system-of-first-order-pdes-odes/1392906#1392906?newreg=b5b4c5c5f25a4a35bd56dbe9eb905e2f where the original equation can be obtained in the first order system without a further application of the operator which is required with the Dirac equation.

Answer (score 1):

Set $c=1$. I'll do the real-$\psi$ case; complex $\psi$ is similar.

The Klein-Gordon equation follows from the Lagrangian density$$\mathcal{L}=(\dot{\psi}^2-(\nabla\psi)^2-m^2\psi^2)/2.$$Physicists usually note this has momentum $\pi=\dot{\psi}$, so the Hamiltonian density is$$\mathcal{H}=\dot{\psi}\pi-\mathcal{L}=(\pi^2+(\nabla\psi)^2+m^2\psi^2)/2.$$Hamilton's equations are then$$\dot{\psi}=\pi,\,\dot{\pi}=\nabla^2\psi-m^2\psi.$$We can remove $\nabla^2$ by defining an alternative Hamiltonian density in terms of [*polymomenta*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9709229.pdf)$$\pi^\mu:=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_\mu\psi}=\partial^\mu\psi$$viz.$$\mathcal{H}=\partial_\mu\psi\cdot\pi^\mu-\mathcal{L}=\frac12\left(\pi_\mu\pi^\mu+m^2\psi^2\right)$$(in $+---$), giving first-order equations$$\partial^\mu\psi=\pi^\mu,\,\partial_\mu\pi^\mu=-m^2\psi.$$

Comment: But we still have second order differentials in the del square. It is not yet first order.

Comment: @Damon You could get around that with a non-standard technique called polymomenta.

Comment: Thanks. I did a quick search for polymomenta but there is no obvious articles to look at. Some are rather thick and dense. Any suggestion?

Comment: I looked at the approach on https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82716428.pdf, from page 508 onward, but things become rather complicated. There may be another way.

Comment: @Damon I think I had something different in mind; see edit.

Comment: So, four gradients (first order terms) are introduced, $\pi^\mu, \mu=0,1,2,3$. The gradients (first order terms) of these gradients can replace the second order terms in the original Gordon-Klein equation. I hope I have understood you correctly.

Comment: @Damon Pretty much. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space) & [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/162235/96494).